# Importing complex.h header file in Xcode .c header file produces compilation errors

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I have a project containing a mixture of Objective c and c files.  In one of the c header files I am trying to import complex.h.  Xcode generates 13 compilation errors connected to NSObjRuntime.h:

NSObjRuntime.h

Parse Issue
Expected identifier or '('

Parse Issue 
Unknown type name 'NSString'...

More compilation errors are produced from NSZone.h.

It looks to me like the errors are coming from Objective C code being unrecognized in a .c file. Should I convert my c files to objective c in order to import complex.h or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3):

> It looks to me like the errors are coming from Objective C code being unrecognized in a .c file.

exactly.

> Should I convert my c files to objective c in order to import complex.h or is there a more elegant solution?

there is no need to use objc in this example. therefore, there is no need to compile it as objc. `complex.h` does not require or include objc headers.

you simply do not include objc headers in your c translations.

if this include is coming from the prefix header, you can use:

```
#if defined(__OBJC__)
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

if it's imported via another header you have included, you will have to consider your include dependencies. sometimes there are unnecessary includes, sometimes you can get away using `#if defined(__OBJC__)`.

Comment: This; the trouble isn't including `complex.h`; it's including `NSObjRuntime.h` in a `.c` file.

Comment: @StephenCanon complex.h doesn't `#include` NSObjRuntime.h -- something else does.

Comment: So, can I import complex.h without somehow dragging along NSObjRuntime.h for the ride?

Comment: @ChristianJ.B.:  Of course.  `#include <complex.h>` in your C file.  I suspect that Justin is right that you have a prefix header that is pulling in other stuff.

Comment: @StephenCanon ok - thanks for clarifying. i also clarified some bits in the answer

Comment: @ChristianJ.B. expanded answer some

Comment: @ChristianJ.B. also note that the issue navigator can walk you through the includes which led to the error.

Comment: @Justin Placing the #if defined(__OBJC__) at the top of my .c header file doesn't seem to help.  I'm still unsure why NSObjRuntime.h is dragged along when I add an include to complex.h.

Comment: @ChristianJ.B. the info's all here. please post your source file so i don't need to guess.

Comment: @Justin.  I think I solved the problem.  Using #include <complex.h> generates error messages, but writing #include </usr/include/complex.h> seems to work fine.  This seems to indicate a name clash, but I have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: @ChristianJ.B. the program - `#include <complex.h>
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) { return 0; }` in a new c project works without issue. i believe the issue exists for an explicable reason, but we should to be able to reproduce it in order to help you.

Comment: @Justin.  Yes.  I checked and it works fine in a new project.  As I said above- providing the full path </usr/include/complex.h> seems to solve my problem, so I suspect there's some sort of name-clash with something else.